# Implementing static table view cells with data in an array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have some data which is pulled from a DB and stored in an array within my `UITableViewController`. However, when I try to put the data inside each of my cells, I get an error that my index is out of the bounds of the array.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellItems.count
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item: ItemPreBasketModel = cellItems[indexPath.row] as! ItemPreBasketModel
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        //Desc cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "descCell"
        let descCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        return descCell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        //Price cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "priceCell"
        let priceCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        return priceCell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        //Quantity cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "quantityCell"
        let quantityCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        return quantityCell
    } else {
        //Submit cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "submitCell"
        let submitCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        return submitCell
    }
}
```

Here is the `cellItems` variable and also where it is populated:

```
var cellItems: NSArray = NSArray() {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {
    cellItems = items
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is the static table view in the storyboard:

[image: setup of the table view]

What I want to do, which I've took out of the code for as it still fails before reaching this part, is to use the 'item' variable I declare inside `cellForRowAt` and populate each of my cell outlets with a part of the object,

i.e: `descCell.descLabel.text = item.name`

The error I get is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the line

```
let descCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
```

Comment: wr u r getting error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a table view controller with static cells and `cellForRowAt` at the same time. You should use **dynamic prototypes** to populate an array dynamically.

To change the content type of your table view, select it in Interface Bulder, open **the Attributes inspector** (the fourth icon from the left in the right sidebar) and select **Dyanmic Prototypes** for **Content** under the **Table View** section.

[image: Dynamic Protoypes setting in Attributes inspector]

Comment: Ah right, should I just load each cell from a xib file and completely bypass static cells ?

Comment: @JamLis You can define prototype cells in Interface Builder as well, you don't necessarily need to use separate xib files.

Comment: Got you, thanks for the quick reply.  I will mark your answer, change to prototype and repost a new thread if any problems arise.